# Importing and storing the data from a Python file

Tags: python

How do I import a Python file and use the user input later?

For example:

```
#mainprogram
from folder import startup
name

#startup
name = input('Choose your name')
```

What I want is to use the startup program to input the name, then be able to use the name later in the main program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access that variable via `startup.name` later in your code.

Comment: Thank you. This works. I'll accept your answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

`name` will be in `startup.name`.  You can use `dir(startup)` to see it.

Or, as an alternate solution:

```
# Assuming from the names that 'folder' is a folder and 'startup' is a Python script
from folder.startup import *
```

now you can just use `name` without the `startup.` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better do your code in classes and functions. 
I suggest you to do:

```
class Startup(object):
@staticmethod
def getName():
    name = ""
    try:
        name = input("Put your name: ")
        print('Name took.')
        return True
    except:
        "Can't get name."
        return False

>> import startup
>> Startup.getName()
```